# regex condition: if group = x then else

Tags: regex

I want to regex the following

```
foo: "/bar/baz/index.html";
```

but `"` could be `'` and obviously you have to use both times the same character so `foo: "...'` won't work.

This is what I already have

```
/templateUrl:[ ]*(['"])[a-z0-9äöü.-_\/\\]*['"][ ]*;/gi
                  ^capture group 1          ^-- here
```

Is it possible to do at `here` something like:

```
if capture group 1 == ' then search for '
else if capture group 1 == " then search for "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple, just refer the first captured group.

```
/templateUrl: *(['"])[a-z0-9äöü.-_\/\\]*\1 *;/gi
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [back reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)  to the captured group 1.. i.e `\1`:

```
/templateUrl:[ ]*(['"])[a-z0-9äöü.-_\/\\]*\1[ ]*;/gi
                   ↑                      ↑
           (captured group 1)       (back reference)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/2)